# Can the status be running after applying the yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes

This is an interview question, It asks apply the following yaml file into your k8s cluster:

```yaml
apiVersion: V1
Kind: pod
Metadata:
  Name: freebox
  Spec:
    Containers:
    - Name: busybox
      Image: busybox:latest
      Imagepullpolicy: IfNotPresent
```

When running the kubectl get pod freebox, could the status be running? Why?

Comment: That's not a valid manifest. If you attempt to apply it, you'll get something like, `error: error validating "pod.yaml": error validating data: kind not set; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Running means that container(s) in your Pod is/are not crashed. Entrypoint started, and command is still running.

Creating that yaml (assuming we fixed case / caps characters aren't at the right place, ...). Pod will be Running. Why: because process has no reason to crash. Because if I inspect that image it uses, entrypoint/cmd is just some /bin/sh -c /bin/sh. Shell will start and keep running.